# Melted neutral wires in a junction box

Tags: electrical

When I came home from vacation I found electrical outlets on one wall not working, so tested them. Found no neutral situation. I pulled them out but they looked good. I found a j-box in attic, opened it and found neutral wires wire nut completely melted. The hot wires and ground wires looked good. What happened?

Comment: How old is the wire nut? The early ones weren't that great, wouldn't bond well and would let go. The newer ones are worlds better.

Comment: about 20 years old

Answer (score 5):

- A badly made connection that deteriorated over time due to heat-cycling and then arcing.
- Ditto with aluminum wires?